# awk read conditions on one row, print the output of another row

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a small issue with `awk` and I can't find the solution.

I would like to swap the NR == in the syntax so I read the conditions of NR ==4 and output NR ==3.

```
awk -F 'NR ==4 { if ($1 < $2 && NF ==4) print $2 "," $4;
                 if ($1 < $2 && NF ==3) print $2 "," "--";
                 if ($1 > $2 && NF ==4) print $1 "," $3;
                 if ($1 > $2 && NF ==3) print $1 "," "--";
               }' infile > outfile
```

What I would like is the above (reads NR ==4 but outputs NR ==3)

```
awk -F 'NR ==4 { if ($1 < $2 && NF ==4) NR ==3 print $2 "," $4;
        NR ==4   if ($1 < $2 && NF ==3) NR ==3 print $2 "," "--";
        NR ==4   if ($1 > $2 && NF ==4) NR ==3 print $1 "," $3;
        NR ==4   if ($1 > $2 && NF ==3) NR ==3 print $1 "," "--";
               }' infile > outfile
```

infile:

```
05:45,11:55,17:37,09:59
0.2,2.3,0.4,2.6
06:18,12:28,18:15
2.3,2.2,0.6
```

desired outfile for this condition where NR==4 $1>$2 && NF==3:

```
12:28, --:--
```

Comment: Sure I will edit the post. Ta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you want and your sample output seems inconsistent with your awk program, but perhaps this will get you started:

```
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
         NR==3 { 
            split($0, line3fields);
            getline;
            if ($1 < $2 && NF==4) print line3fields[2], line3fields[4]
            if ($1 < $2 && NF==3) print line3fields[2], "--:--"
            if ($1 > $2 && NF==4) print line3fields[1], line3fields[3]
            if ($1 > $2 && NF==3) print line3fields[1], "--:--"
         }
         ' infile > outfile
```

- `BEGIN` block: Since your input and output are `,`-separated, sets both the input (`FS`) and output (`OFS`) field separators to `,`.
- Next, line *3* is processed: its fields - via function `split()` - are stored in array variable `line3fields` for later use.
- `getline` line then reads the *next* line - line 4 in this case - into `$0`, and its tokens into `$1`, `$2`, ...
- The `if` statement therefore operates on line *4*'s fields, whereas the `print` statement references line *3*'s tokens via array `line3fields`.

As for your original code:

Once you've selected a matching line with pattern `NR==4`, the associated action (block) will only be processed for that line; therefore, inside your block, you can't refer directly to *other* lines with conditions such as `NR==3`.

Your options are:

- Use `getline` to read subsequent line(s), as in my code above.
- Use *separate* pattern-action pairs (e.g., one for `NR==3` and another for `NR==4`, and store lines of interest in variables for use in a later action).

Comment: Hi mklement0, it's kind of what I've got in awk. But sorry if it's not that clear, I struggle sometimes to explain clearly. I would like to read the condition of row 4. So while reading row 4 if $1>$2 and number of fields ==3 then print row 3 $1,--:--

Comment: thanks great thanks, it's gave me a good starting point. Many thanks. :-)

Comment: @IanGooch: My pleasure; glad to hear it works for you.